# Failure to trace some syscalls with eBPF

Tags: ebpf, bcc-bpf

I am using bcc to trace several syscalls, why is it that I can trace syscalls like `write`, `close`, `fchown` using a simple `attach_kprobe` but can't trace syscalls like `stat`, `fstat`?

I assume that are other syscalls that I can't trace but haven't found which ones. How can I trace `stat`, `fstat` and how are these different from the usual `write`, `close` ?

Sample code:

```
b = BPF(text=prog)
b.attach_kprobe(event=b.get_syscall_fnname("fstat"), fn_name="syscall_fstat")
```

In my prog I do a simple print

```
int syscall_fstat(void *ctx){
    bpf_trace_printk("fstat\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using in both cases? What makes you think you can't trace them? Do you have an error message?

Comment: No error message. To trigger fstat I believe a "ls" should be enough but I never see output that confirms this. On the other hand when using write I am able to see the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using stat I should be using newstat.

Comment: Indeed, if you look at [the source code](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/v0.12.0/tools/statsnoop.py#L112) of one of the bcc examples tracing `stat`, you can see that it attempts several names: `stat`, `statfs` and `newstat`. Congrats on finding the one you need for your system :)